# With Windows Azure Tools, why do I receive Invalid access to memory location?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, azure

I have the following installed:

- Visual Studio 2010
- Windows Azure Tools, v1.5
- Windows Azure SDK, v1.5

When I attempt to debug a "Web Role", I receive the following error:
"Windows Azure Tools: Invalid access to memory location"

This shows up in the "General" output of Visual Studio.  When this happens, it cancels the build/debugging session.  This does not happen every time. If I try again, it might work.

Memory looks like this:

- Total: 8061
- Cached: 969
- Available: 1468
- Free: 524

Roughly 81% in use.

So, the question is, why am I receiving this error?

Comment: Sounds like you might need to open a support ticket.

Comment: This is bizarre. Just started getting this error today and I've been building azure apps for over a year.

Comment: Just started getting this with SDK 1.6.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/736847/windows-azure-devfabric-invalid-access-to-memory-location

Comment: Thanks Robotsushi; I went ahead and helped up-vote that bug

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I’ve documented the cause and solution for this bug here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/10/31/compute-emulator-invalid-access-to-memory-location.aspx

The solution is to install Windows 8.1 or install the KB 2588507 hot fix (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2588507/en-us) to correct the kernel address-conversion routines in older 64-bit versions of Windows.

Comment: This hotfix appears to be gone... anyone have a copy for the love of god?!@?!#

Comment: Yes it has gone. But after changing the language to german and clicking "Hotfix download available" on the MS-page for the hotfix I finally came to a site where I could request a download link by providing my e-mail address. https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/hotfix/kbhotfix?kbnum=2588507&kbln=de

Answer (score 3):

Although it sounds like sacrificing a dead chicken over my PC I tried the instructions here:

http://old.stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2008/04/29/hacking-visual-studio-to-use-more-than-2gigabytes-of-memory.aspx

to persuade my Visual Studio 2010 to stop giving me memory-related errors of this kind. Worked a charm, and *appeared* to improve general performance of Visual Studio altogether.

However, as with most voodoo chants, your mileage may vary. Take backups.

Comment: How did this solution work out for you ? Did you encounter any problems ?

Comment: Things /appeared/ to be more stable. However, I'm finding 64-bit Windows to be much better for Azure work than the old 32-bit machine I was using.

Comment: Jeremy, that might be on the account of the increased amount of memory available (64 over 32) - but that is just an educated guess.

Comment: The link is dead. Long live the link: http://old.stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2008/04/29/hacking-visual-studio-to-use-more-than-2gigabytes-of-memory.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I too have seen this error when attempting to debug. It appears to be when Visual Studio has problems starting the Compute and / or Storage Emulators. Starting them manually before running the application seems to do the trick.

I cannot begin to knowledgeably speculate on what causes this error, however since a lack of understanding has rarely stopped me before: my working hypothesis is that it may well be memory related since this error only *seems* to appear if Visual Studio (2010) has been running for a while (ie once VS's memory usage has had time to creep up).

Comment: Hey rich, I still receive these errors today as well and I have found that the only sure-fire way to fix it is to shut down the emulator and restart VS

Answer (score 0):

I had this exception today while testing my worker role locally. Turns out that you can get this exception message pop-up from the Azure Storage Emulator when you specify a local "data"-folder that's too large for your machine.

In my case I had a ConfigurationSetting "DataDirSizeMB" set to "256000" (256GB!) in ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg, when my machine only had a 111GB HD... After I changed the setting to just "100" (100MB) everything worked locally :D

Be sure to check all settings so that the Local.cscfg is configured for local-use, and the Cloud.cscfg for Azure-use.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem which I solved by restarting the Visual Studio (running with DOMAIN account) as Administrator.