# Windows Azure Emulator "Invalid access to memory location."

Tags: c#-4.0, azure, visual-studio-debugging

i work at a project with Windows Azure and when i want to Debug the Solution the Azure Emulator throws an Error (***but this ist not always!***):

German Error:

"**Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio
Unzulässiger Zugriff auf einen Speicherbereich**"

English Error:

"**Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio
Invalid access to memory location**"

If there any fix for this Error?

Comment: could you please specify your tool versions (VS, Azure SDK, ..) and have a look at the already existing Q/As

Comment: possible duplicate of [With Windows Azure Tools, why do I receive Invalid access to memory location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917955/with-windows-azure-tools-why-do-i-receive-invalid-access-to-memory-location)

Comment: Yeah it seems to be the same. Thanks I searched about this though, but didn't find anything close to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that [was fixed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/10/31/compute-emulator-invalid-access-to-memory-location.aspx) in Windows 8.1, however for older versions of Windows there is a [KB 2588507 hotfix available](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2588507)

Comment: The link on that Microsoft site is broken. Is there anywhere else I can still get this hotfix?

Answer (score 1):

See the workaround: [MsConnect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/736847/windows-azure-devfabric-invalid-access-to-memory-location)

> Shutdown the Compute and Storage Emulator and restart Visual Studio. (It' s anoying yes, but then it works another 6-9 times)

It worked for me :)

Comment: Well this is awkward because I created the workaround that you posted on MsConnect :D

Answer (score 0):

If you reinstall the Windows Azure SDK, does it work fine?

Comment: No, I upgraded it to the newest SDK Version (2.0) with VS 2012 and the error is still the same...

Comment: It's a bug in the kernel, nothing to do with the SDK